# Cannot get Negative Lookahead regexp to properly match

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match strings that do not have .jsp/.jspx extensions in Java and am having a lot of difficult with the negative lookahead pattern.

Given a bunch of strings:

```
String string1 = "templateName";
String string2 = "some/path"
String string3 = "basic/filename/no/extension"
String string4 = "some/path/to/file.jsp"
String string5 = "alternative/path/to/file.jspx"
```

I'm trying to find a regex that matches the first 3 and not the last 2.

I would have thought a regex with a negative lookahead would work.

Ex:

```
Pattern p = new Pattern.compile( "(.+)(?!\\.jsp[x]?)")
```

But that pattern seems to match all the above strings.  I initially thought that group 1 might be too greedy, so I've tried (.+?), but that does not help either.

This [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/977294/827480) does a very good job of explain the negative lookahead, but it isn't helping me unfortunately find the right combination.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Your pattern says, "If you can find _any_ non-empty sequence of characters that is not immediately followed by .jsp or .jspx, then it's a match."  So of course it will match `some/path/to/file.jsp` because it could match `s`, `so`, or anything as long as it doesn't include the last slash.  See anubhava's answers.  The second one uses negative lookahead to fail if the beginning of the string is followed by a non-empty sequence of characters followed by `.jsp[x]` (if the `.jsp[x]` is at the end of the string).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `negative lookbehind` as:

```
Pattern p = new Pattern.compile( "^(.+)(?<!\\.jspx?)$" );
```

OR you can use `negative lookahead` as:

```
Pattern p = new Pattern.compile( "^(?!.+?\\.jspx?$)(.+)$" );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately, I do not understand how either pattern works.  Are you able to provide a little explanation as to how those patterns match?  I've never been able to properly grasp the constructs of the lookahead or lookbehind exoressions.

Comment: @EricB.: FOr best explanation on lookarounds please visit this simple doc: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Once you're satisfied with my answer, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another negative lookbehind:

```
Pattern p = new Pattern.compile(".*(?<!.jspx?)$");
```

`(?<!.jspx?)` is a negated lookbehind assertion, which means that before the end of the string, there is no .jsp or .jspx

You are looking behind the end of string $

Reference:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

[Regex not ending with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398471/regex-not-ending-with)