# Define regular expression that matches urls that end with digits unless anything else comes after

Tags: regex

I'm using Scrapy to scrape a web site. I'm stuck at defining properly the rule for extracting links.
Specifically, I need help to write a regular expression that allows urls like:

`https://discuss.dwolla.com/t/the-dwolla-reflector-is-now-open-source/1352`
`https://discuss.dwolla.com/t/enhancement-dwolla-php-updated-to-2-1-3/1180`
`https://discuss.dwolla.com/t/updated-java-android-helper-library-for-dwollas-api/108`

while forbidding urls like this one

`https://discuss.dwolla.com/t/the-dwolla-reflector-is-now-open-source/1352/12`

In other words, I want urls that end with digits (i.e., `/1352` in the example abpve), unless after these digits there is anything after (i.e., `/12` in the example above)

I am by no means an expert of regular expressions, and I could only come up with something like `\/(\d+)$`, or even this one `^https:\/\/discuss.dwolla.com\/t\/\S*\/(\d+)$`, but both fail at excluding the unwanted urls since they all capture the last digits in the address.

**--- UPDATE ---**

Sorry for not being clear in the first place. This addition is to clarify that the digits at the of URLS can change, so the `/1352` is not fixed. As such, another example of urls to be accepted is also:

`https://discuss.dwolla.com/t/updated-java-android-helper-library-for-dwollas-api/108`

Comment: How will you define *a certain way*?

Comment: Please, see the text, I cannot define it any better that that in the title, because it would be wrong if I wrote "...does not end with digits". Thanks

Comment: Possibly a specific instance of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398471/regex-not-ending-with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the simplest way:

```
[^\/\d][^\/]*\/\d+$
```

or to restrict to a particular domain:

```
^https?:\/\/discuss.dwolla.com\/.*[^\/\d][^\/]*\/\d+$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/SZgidVcQ6T).

This regex requires the last part to be all digits, and the 2nd last part to have at least 1 non-digit.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Saw the live demo. Your regex does not seem to work with this one though. `https://discuss.dwolla.com/t/enhancement-dwolla-php-updated-to-2-1-3/1180`. Is it because it contains numbers in the middle, other than letters and dashes?

See [here](http://rubular.com/r/2Bd65ei3If), I've added more examples to your live demo.

Comment: @bateman I see. Hopefully that last edit is more to your liking (new live demo link too). Thanks for making the job easier by augmenting the demo and posting the new link.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work now! Running the script and get back here right after. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a java regex may fit your requirements in java style. You can specify number of digits **N** you are excepting in `{N}`

```
^https://discuss.dwolla.com/t/[\\w|-]+/[\\d]+$
```

Comment: No, the number of digits may vary, is not fixed. They're post ids. Thanks!

Comment: you can range the digits {M,N} from M to N  OR {M,} at least M number of digits is required

Comment: Thanks, this regexp does not seem to work always, see here for example: https://regex101.com/r/kL6hB8/2