# Java: Match Regex unless ending with arbitrary suffix

Tags: java, regex

### **What I want do:**

Using Java, I want to match a RegEx pattern, unless the match is immediately followed by a "poison" suffix.

**Exemples:**

```
 "legitString" RETURNS "legitString"

 "legitString blabla" RETURNS "legitString"

 "legitString PoisonousSuffix" RETURNS "legitString"

 "legitStringPoisonousSuffix" RETURNS no match
```

### **My use case:**

I need to parse as much references from a file as I can, following a particular pattern.
But some lines of the file are truncated, and not always at the same length(!).

Luckily, when this happens, the line ends with ">>". I have to assume the reference is truncated and I have to discard it. So ">>$" would be the poisonous suffix in my case. 
On the other hand, if ">>" is in the middle of the text, I should safely extract the reference as I would normally do. (The reference ends with digits, but the number of digit can be different each time so I can't use that.)

**So in my case:**

```
"REF" RETURNS "REF"

"REF >>" RETURNS "REF"

"REF>>" RETURNS nothing

"REF>> bla " RETURNS "REF" // because in my case, the poison is only poisonous if in the end
```

I've seen: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info
But I tried the syntax

```
myRegex(?!>>$)
```

and it looks wrong. It truncates the last legit digit of the reference when the line ends with ">>", which is the worst scenario: a corrupted reference going through.

I've seen: [Regex for string not ending with given suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398471/regex-for-string-not-ending-with-given-suffix)   but :

```
myRegex(?:(?!>>).).$
```

rejects legitimate references.

### **My exact regex (without poison) :**

```
   \b(SWN-)?WZ-SB\d{2}(-\d{2}){2}-[A-Z]?\d*
```

**should return SWN-WZ-SB00-49-03-C11 for:**

```
"SWN-WZ-SB00-49-03-C11>> bla"

"SWN-WZ-SB00-49-03-C11 >>  "

"SWN-WZ-SB00-49-03-C11 >>"

"SWN-WZ-SB00-49-03-C11 >> bla"
```

**and nothing for:**

```
"SWN-WZ-SB00-49-03-C11>>"
```

### **Bonus**

Is there a way to generalize and have function taking regexPattern and poisonousSuffix and returning a safeRegexPattern?

Thanks

Comment: The first one and the last one confuse me.  Both legit strings end with a ">>".  It's a little hard to see how the first is correct and the second is wrong.  Is that possibly a mistake?  Basically it seems like both end with the "poisonous suffix."

Comment: IF I understand correctly, I think I would just read each line and discard any that end with the poisonous suffix, ">>".  Then parse as normal.  This seems easier than trying to cram everything into one regex.  Might be easier on your maintainers too trying to read an overly complicated regex.

Comment: @markspace In my use case, my poisonous suffix is not ">>", but ">> + EndOfLine", which I believe to be ">>$" in Regex.

So the end of line is just relevant in my specific case.

I will edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: That's why I said "read each line."

Comment: @Akita Your requirements are out of sync with the examples. If your suffix is `>>$`, then `SWN-WZ-SB00-49-03-C11>> bla` should result in `SWN-WZ-SB00-49-03-C11>> bla`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, because even if the poison is not active in this case, the rest of the regex should kick in and keep only the reference.

Comment: @markspace A dedicated " pattern of pattern" would be useful to create a function out of it. 
But If I don't manage to implement the poison idea or find a usefull library, I will do this of course.

Comment: @Akita after looking at your updated requirements I have updated my answer to account for your suffix.

Comment: Does the line continuation/truncate symbol only exist after a complete REF or can it appear practically everywhere?

Comment: Depending on the file/string size, you could remove all >> and treat the string as a single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to use conditionals. Here is the pattern I used.

`(?(?![\w-]+>>$)(?:([^\s>]*)(?:.*))|([^\w\W]))`

I'll provide a breakdown for you:

`(?...)` is an `if` conditional

`(?![\w-]+>>$)` checks to see if the string contains the poisonous suffix

`(([^ \n>]*)(?:.*))` captures everything up until you run into a space or >

`|` OR

`([^\w\W])` captures nothing.

So the syntax for an if conditional is (?If(condition)then|else). What this pattern does is if the string does not contain the suffix, return the string up until the first space, but if it does, match nothing.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qBlF62/33)