# Regex to match URLs that does not end with a particular word or word set

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to create a reg-ex which matches URLs that does not end with a particular word(s). Here are some examples:

I want to match:

```
https://google.com/default-category/all-products.html/22-oz-full-color-stadium-cup-white
https://google.com/catalog/product/view/id/9351/s/plant-award/category/3/
https://google.com/all-products/volleyball/stress-shape
```

And, I don't want to match:

```
https://google.com/all-products/timber-bases-other/bases-gloves/tic-tac-1/tic-tac-1/
https://google.com/all-products/timber-bases-other/bases-gloves/tic-tac-1/tic-tac-1/tic-tac-1/tic-tac-1/tic-tac-1/
```

Here is the regex I am using:

```
https?:\/\/(www\.)?google\.com\/(default-category\/all-products\.html|catalog\/product\/view\/id|all-products)\/[\w-\/]+(?!tic-tac-1)
```

The problem is, all the words follow a similar pattern. The wildcard `([\w-]+\/?)+` matches even the word `tic-tac-1`.

How do I ensure it does not happen?

Here is the RegExr link where I try it out: https://regexr.com/4chb8

Comment: Are you extracting them from a larger test or test as separate standalone strings?

Comment: They are separate standalone strings

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33868646/3832970, that is your answer. `^(?!.*tic-tac-1/$)`

Comment: Try `^(?!.*tic-tac-1/$)[\w-]+/(?:[\w-]+/)*` https://regex101.com/r/PP5tjo/1

Comment: That solution [works for you](https://regex101.com/r/D7ls5h/1). Else, edit the question to explain why it does not. Even if you want to precise your pattern like `^(?!.*\/tic-tac-1\/$)\w+(?:[-\/]\w+)*\/$`, it is still the same duplicate.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! I have updated the question with actual scenario. Sorry, I was a bit confused.

Comment: It is still the same dupe: your pattern should be `^(?!.*FORBIDDEN_WORD$)YOUR_MATCHING_PATTERN$`. Try `(?!.*tic\/$)` lookahead, see https://regex101.com/r/MIugBt/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The last solution worked! Thank you. Interestingly, it does not work on `regexer`, but it's working on `regex101`. Not sure if it's a problem with the editor.