# How to create a regex expression for Safari

Tags: regex, safari

I am trying to create a regex expression that does not allow some string to start or end with "-". I tryied this one so far, but it does not works on Safari.

.+(?

Any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks in advance

.+(?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16398502/3832970 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/33868646/3832970

Answer (score 2):

Will this work?

```
^([^\-])(.*)([^\-])$
```

Or this version if you can also have 1 or 2 character values

```
^([^\-])(.*)([^\-])$|^(([^\-]){0,2})$
```