# .net regex - strings that don't contain full stop on last list item

Tags: .net, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to use .net regex for identifying strings in XML data that don't contain a full stop before the last  tag. I have not much experience with regex. I'm not sure what I need to change & why to get the result I'm looking for.

There are line breaks and carriage returns at end of each line in the data.

A schema is used for the XML.

Example of good XML Data:

```
<randlist prefix="unorder">
    <item>abc</item>
    <item>abc</item>
    <item>abc.</item>
</randlist>
```

Example of bad XML Data - regexp should give matches - no full stop preceding last `</item>`:

```
<randlist prefix="unorder">
    <item>abc</item>
    <item>abc</item>
    <item>abc</item>
</randlist>
```

Reg exp pattern I tried that didn't work in the bad XML data (not tested on good XML data):

```
^<randlist \w*=[\S\s]*\.*[^.]<\/item>[\n]*<\/randlist>$
```

Results using http://regexstorm.net/tester:

```
0 matches
```

Results using https://regex101.com/:

```
0 matches
```

This question is different to the following imo, due to full stop and start of string criteria:

[Regex for string not ending with given suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398471/regex-for-string-not-ending-with-given-suffix)

Explanation from [3](https://regex101.com/):

```
/
^<randlist \w*=[\S\s]*\.*[^.]<\/item>[\n]*<\/randlist>$
/
gm
^ asserts position at start of a line
<randlist  matches the characters <randlist  literally (case sensitive)
\w* matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
= matches the character = literally (case sensitive)
Match a single character present in the list below [\S\s]*
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\S matches any non-whitespace character (equal to [^\r\n\t\f\v ])
\s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
\.* matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Match a single character not present in the list below [^.]
. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
< matches the character < literally (case sensitive)
\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
item> matches the characters item> literally (case sensitive)
Match a single character present in the list below [\n]*
< matches the character < literally (case sensitive)
\/ matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
randlist> matches the characters randlist> literally (case sensitive)
$ asserts position at the end of a line
Global pattern flags
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```

Comment: Nested structures are best dealt with XML parser.

Comment: All you need is adding a star (*) to your regex: ^<randlist \w*=[\S\s]*\.*[^.]*<\/item>[\n]*<\/randlist>$

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. I have posted an updated question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59858437/net-regex-strings-that-dont-contain-full-stop-preceding-last-item-atte

Answer (score 0):

@Silvanas is absolutely correct. You should not use Regex for this problem, you should use some form of XML parser to read the data and find the lines with `.`. However, if for some horrible reason you MUST use Regex, and If your data is structured exactly like your example, then the Regex solution would be the following:

`^\s+<item>[^<]*?(?<=\.)<\/item>$`

**If there *ARE* any matches with that regex, your xml is malformed**. But again, this regex fails if the whitespace isn't correct, if there's anything else on the line, if the tags arent `<item>..</item>`, and so on and so on. Again, you would be far, far better off not using Regex for this problem unless you can **absolutely guarantee** that everything but the `.` is going to be well-formed XML

EDIT: If the opening and closing tag are on the same line, but it isn't necessarily titled 'item', and may have attributes, go ahead and try the following:

```
^\s+<([^<>\s]+)[^<>]*>[^<>]*?(?<=\.)<\/\1>$

Breakdown:
^           anchor to beginning of line
\s+         skip over any whitespace
<           found what looks like an opening tag
([^[]\s]+)  match the first word found after the "<", store in capture group 1
[^<>]*>     match whatever remain until the closing ">"
[^<>]*?     match all of the contents up until the next "<"
(?<=\.)     ensure the last character was a "."
<\/\1>      match a closing tag where the text after the / is the same as the first word of the opening tag (stored in capture group 1)
$           anchor to end of line
```

Make sure you have the MultiLine regex option set, otherwise ^ and $ will match the beginning/end of the entire string. As with before, any matches with this regex mean the XML is poorly formed on that line.

Comment: The xml is well formed, it has to be that is the whole purpose of using a schema to control the structure and content