# Java Replace Only Particular String

Tags: regex, string, replace, replaceall

I have string `"foo_FOO1"` and `"foo1_FOO1"`. I want to replace only the part `"foo"` with `"x0"` and the word `"foo1"` is not included. So the result of `"foo_FOO1"` has to be `"x0_FOO1"` and `"foo1_FOO1"` remains the same. Could you give me the solution in Java, please?
I tried to use
`str.replaceAll("foo", "x0")`
but all string that contains `"foo"` will be replaced with `"x0"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketchy, but try to replace the `_` too. Since `foo1_` does not match `foo_`, Java will not replace it.

```java
final String test = "foo_FOO1 foo1_FOO1";

final String result = test.replaceAll("foo_", "x0_");
System.out.println(result);
```

**Result**:

```
x0_FOO1 foo1_FOO1
```

Tests:

```java
private String replaceFoo(final String value) {
    return value.replaceAll("foo_", "x0_");
}

@Test
public void testMultipleLines() {
    Assert.assertEquals("x0_FOO1 foo1_FOO1", replaceFoo("foo_FOO1 foo1_FOO1"));
    Assert.assertEquals("x0_FOO1\n\nfoo1_FOO1", replaceFoo("foo_FOO1\n\nfoo1_FOO1"));
}

@Test
public void testSingleLine() {
    Assert.assertEquals("x0_FOO1", replaceFoo("foo_FOO1"));
    Assert.assertEquals("foo1_FOO1", replaceFoo("foo1_FOO1"));
}
```

If the given String may not have a `_`, have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16398813/15257712

Comment: thank you, but the string "foo_FOO1" and "foo1_FOO1" is not in one line. it's just an example with 2 cases :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Inline, single and multi-line works fine for me. Am i overlooking any test cases? (I attached mine above)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was just not focused on your solution :D yup, it works. thank you!!!

Comment: I'm glad that it works! Will you mark the question as resolved?